# Does PostQuitMessage() goes into WM_DESTROY or WM_CLOSE?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to create a very basic window using the Win32 API and it's been a long time since I've done this.

I think my message loop is okay, but when I close the opened window, the application is still running. It looks like the message loop never gets a `WM_QUIT` message. However, I am calling `PostQuitMessage` and a message box confirms I called it.

What is wrong with this minimalist code?

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
        WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        MessageBox(NULL, L"destroy", L"info", MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, w_param, l_param);
    }

    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE h_instance, HINSTANCE h_prev_instance,
        LPSTR cmd_line, int n_cmd_show) {
    WNDCLASS wnd_class;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL ret;

    wnd_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wnd_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wnd_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wnd_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wnd_class.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wnd_class.hInstance = h_instance;
    wnd_class.lpfnWndProc = window_proc;
    wnd_class.lpszClassName = L"MyWindowClass";
    wnd_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wnd_class.style = 0;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wnd_class)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"cannot register window class",
            L"error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        L"MyWindowClass",
        L"",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        h_instance,
        NULL
    );

    while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (ret == -1) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"error", L"", MB_OK);
        } else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, L"quitting now", L"info", MB_OK);

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

The `GetMessage` doc says the function returns 0 when it reads a `WM_QUIT` message. Howcome `PostQuitMessage` is called and `GetMessage` never returns 0?

Thank you, Win32 gurus.

Comment: @KenWhite Traditionally, `WM_CLOSE` invokes `DestroyWindow()`, which sends `WM_DESTROY`, where your handler invokes `PostQuiteMessage()`, which posts WM_QUIT to the thread message queue causing `GetMessage()` to return 0. This is why he's here in the first place. the only thing I see odd is the messagebox in the `WM_DESTROY` handler. If i had a windows box in front of me I'd try this, because it must be too simple a problem to see.

Comment: @KenWhite, according to the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "It is typically used in response to a WM_DESTROY message."

Comment: @MarkRansom I concur (hope that was obvious in the prior comment).

Comment: @WhozCraig and @MarkRansom: Got it. I read the `remarks` rather than the main topic. Deleting my comments. Thanks for the correction - it's been too long since I had to do this stuff.  :-)

Comment: @WhozCraig, I sometimes have regret for having relied on MFC for so many years - it hides many of these important nitty-gritty details from you.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well I've avoided MFC since VC++ 4.0, opting instead for raw WIN32 like this or WTL, so I think we're covered, especially if David H. is around, I found a window machine, so I can finally try this.

Comment: That's because I read onto MSDN (about `PostQuitMessage`): _Indicates to the system that a thread has made a request to terminate (quit). It is typically used in response to a WM_DESTROY message._ It is true, however, that if I replace `WM_DESTROY` by `WM_CLOSE`, it works (exits) without any error. So why this documentation? They even give [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598.aspx#destroying_win) example, which I tried and doesn't seem to work (calling `DestroyWindow` from `WM_CLOSE` and `PostQuitMessage` from `WM_DESTROY`).

Comment: BTW I removed all the `MessageBox` calls and as I was expecting, it doesn't change anything. All this stuff is very linear; you can `Sleep` for hours anywhere in this code and it's still going to work when it finally wakes up. But I'm still stuck in the message loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its your `GetMessage()` loop.

You're passing your window handle to that loop, thereby filtering out all application-thread messages and only receiving messages to *that* window. .

Change this:

```
while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0)) != 0) 
//  Note window handle =========^
```

To this:

```
while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) 
//  Note no handle =============^
```

And your application thread queue should now be monitored by your `GetMessage()` loop.

**Why:** `GetMessage()` invokes can be tailored to monitor a specific window handle's message queue. The application WM_QUIT is not posted to a window handle queue; it is posted to the thread-message queue, which can only pull messages off the queue by using `GetMessage()` (perhaps `PeekMessage()` as well, but its been too long for me to remember) with *no* target window handle to specifically monitor.

Comment: I just found that out (by looking at an online demo), came back here to answer and found your answer. That's right! Thank you. However, what's the problem with the `ret` variable?

Comment: @eepp the return type of `GetMessage()` is `BOOL`. I know, its defined as `int`, but technically Microsoft wants all `BOOL` API's to only be checked for zero (`FALSE`) or non-zero value. Any specific value apart from zero or not should not be relied on. If more than just zero vs. non-zero return values are needed, the API will return `int` or some such instead with specific documentation on the possible return values. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Good to know, but look at their example [right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx). I just don't know why they made this function return `BOOL` if they want us to check for -1, 0 and anything positive...

Comment: @eepp you're absolutely right about the inconsistency. Its likely a long legacy line reaching back literally over two decades. If `GetMessage()` can returning anything specific besides specific zero or unspecific non-zero that should be testable, they shouldn't have it declared BOOL. Its the "different *versions* of 'TRUE'" that I find ironic. But you're correct, they documented this, so I'd run with it (holding my nose the whole way). Since they did document this case, i'll pull the comment from the answer posted.

Comment: For added hilarity the new definition for the return from a wndproc is INT_PTR. (DialogProcs were the ones that were BOOL... unfortunately they still are). As mentioned this stuff is from the 16-bit real mode days.

Comment: @HerrJoebob Outstanding. The INT_PTR makes more sense, since WndProc can return pointers, but the DlgProc ret-val still cracks me up.

Comment: The `BOOL` goes back to early C code, where `false` was typically zero, and `TRUE` was defined as `!FALSE`. IOW, anything other than zero was evaluated as not equal to zero, and therefore was true instead. @WhozCraig: This one I remember, anyway, and +1 for the answer. ;-)